# Send a specific email in HTML and the rest in plain text

Tags: buddypress

I have 3 different email types on my wordpress website.

- Registration Email
- Forgotten Password Emails
- All other Emails

I want my registration and forgotten password emails to be in HTML and then all other emails sent in plain text.

I use BuddyPress to handle my registrations and have managed to change the the registration emails with the following:

```
/* Custom user registration email */
function set_bp_message_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}

add_filter( 'bp_core_signup_send_validation_email_message', 'custom_buddypress_activation_message', 10, 3 );

function custom_buddypress_activation_message( $message, $user_id, $activate_url ) {
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_bp_message_content_type' );
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    return 'MY HTML MESSAGE HERE'

}
```

I have another function created to modify the registration email as per the below:

```
/* Change ccontent type to HTML */
add_action( 'login_form_retrievepassword', function()
{   add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function() {  return text/html;  });
});

/* Change Subject */
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_title', function() {
    return 'Complete-Models Password Reset';
});

/* Change the message/body of the email */
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', 'rv_new_retrieve_password_message', 10, 2 );

function rv_new_retrieve_password_message( $message, $key ){
    // Bail if username or email is not entered

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) )
        return;

    // Get user's data
    if ( strpos( $_POST['user_login'], '@' ) ) { # by email
        $user_data = get_user_by( 'email', trim( $_POST['user_login'] ) );
    } else { 
        # by username
        $login = trim( $_POST['user_login'] );
        $user_data = get_user_by( 'login', $login );
    }
    // Store some info about the user
    $user_fname = $user_data->user_firstname;
    $user_login = $user_data->user_login;
    $user_email = $user_data->user_email;

    // Assembled the URL for resetting the password
    $reset_url = add_query_arg(array(
        'action' => 'rp',
        'key' => $key,
        'login' => rawurlencode( $user_login )
    ), wp_login_url() );

    return 'HTML MESSAGE HERE';

}
```

The registration email works perfectly however the forgotten password email still sends as plain text. Any ideas how i can set a specific email as HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding quotes around the return value:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function() { return 'text/html'; });
```